# getnameinfo is not resolving IP

Tags: hostname

I have gateway installed on Ubuntu, and not able to get hostname for local IPs, using nslookup or programmatically using getnameinfo
nslookup gives:

```
fuad@URLF:~$ nslookup 192.168.1.107
Server: 127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53


** server can't find 107.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

The DNS configuration is shown below using nuclei:

```
nmcli device show|grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]: 41.128.225.225
```

I tried adding router as DNS using nuclei:

```
nmcli connection edit type ethernet
set ipv4.DNS 192.168.1.1
```

saved and quit but still the same

below is all the output of nmcli show:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE: bridge0
GENERAL.TYPE: bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR: 70:F3:95:09:2F5
GENERAL.MTU: 1500
GENERAL.STATE: 100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION: Bridge connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]: 192.168.1.135/24
IP4.GATEWAY: 192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]: dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]: 41.128.225.225
IP6.ADDRESS[1]: fd2c:d457:2852:1:f1c2:dc5d:d6e:6e6f/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]: fe80::f965:9dc3:db65:ea36/64
IP6.GATEWAY: 
IP6.ROUTE[1]: dst = fd2c:d457:2852:1::/64, nh = ::, mt = 425


GENERAL.DEVICE: enp0s25
GENERAL.TYPE: ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR: 70:F3:95:09:2F5
GENERAL.MTU: 1500
GENERAL.STATE: 100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION: bridge0 slave 2
GENERAL.CON-PATH: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER: on


GENERAL.DEVICE: enp17s0
GENERAL.TYPE: ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR: 78:54:2E:70:07:30
GENERAL.MTU: 1500
GENERAL.STATE: 100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION: bridge0 slave 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER: on


GENERAL.DEVICE: lo
GENERAL.TYPE: loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR: 00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU: 65536
GENERAL.STATE: 10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION: --
GENERAL.CON-PATH: --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]: 127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY: 
IP6.ADDRESS[1]: ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

Comment: Fuad - welcome to SE.  Suggest you sort out the formatting.  I've done some, to help you understand how indents work etc.

Answer (score 1):

The address 192.168.1.107 is part of the 192.168.0.0/16 block defined in RFC 1819 "Address Allocation for Private Internets". It is not unique on the Internet: there are probably millions of hosts using this same address. An external DNS server has no way of knowing what host name to return for this address.